# How to call a service when the app starts in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a `routing-back-service` which on load starts recognizing the routes. In one of my component(member-profile) I want to make the back button work as a browser back button using this service to get the previous url.

The problem with this is, if I call the service from member-profile component on clicking back, for the first time it is not getting the previous route and it works fine later on.

How to call this service while the app starts, so that it can recognize the routes from the start?

`routing-back.service`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingBackService {
  private previousUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
        pairwise()
      ).subscribe((e: any) => {
        this.previousUrl = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }
}
```

`member-profile.ts`

```
goBack() {
    const currentUser = this.userService.get();
    if (currentUser.isUserAdmin) {
      this.previousUrl = this.back.getPreviousUrl();
      this.router.navigate([ this.previousUrl ]);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([ '/' ]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use built in https://angular.io/api/common/Location#back? Is there a very specific use case that calls for a service? Other than that, declaring the service in your AppComponent (main module cmp) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

May be putting it in the NgOnInit method on the app level .ts file helps?

Comment: I then cannot get the url in different compoenents unless I create a service